# Who blocks cross domain AJAX request browser or webserver or both?

Tags: ajax

Cross domain AJAX requests are reported as "aborted" in firebug. I know this is supposed to be  security feature but where exactly these requests get rejected ? At the browser end or at the server end ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browser - they don't get sent at all. If you check your HTTP traffic (e.g. using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)), you'll see that there is no corresponding HTTP request initiated for those aborted AJAX requests.

(That is also the only place where such blocking makes sense, as the server doesn't have a reliable way to distinguish between AJAX requests and normal requests; only the browser has enough context to make such decision.)

Comment: can we make a browser ourselves which bypasses this check?

Comment: @emaillenin You can, but I won't be using it. The same-origin policy is a security feature -- I won't be using a browser that enables XSS attacks.

Comment: I often see a "crossdomain.xml" file in wbe directories of various apps. What purpose does it serve ?

Comment: @Akshar Prabhu Desai: That would be an entirely different question :) This is the first hit for "what is crossdomain.xml": http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html - apparently that's something to do with Flash etc.

Comment: @lonesomeday I will use it only on sites where I feel hacking is intended ;)

Comment: @whoever-will-make-such-browser: Please also implement [RFC3514](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3514.html) support.